# Finding the dimensions of a cuboid for minimal surface area

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have no idea how to even start thinking with this problem:

Using the theorem for extrema of a function with two variables, find the dimensions of a parallelepiped with rectangular faces and fixed volume V such that its surface area is minimal.

Comment: Is it not just a cuboid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be a parallelepiped of dimensions $a,b,c$, its volume is given by $V=abc$ and its surface is $S=2ab+2bc+2ac$. Let us assume that $V>0$, then $c=\frac{V}{ab}$ and thus $S=2ab+2\frac{V}{a}+2\frac{V}{b}$. Now, we look for a maximum of $(a,b)\mapsto S=S(a,b)$ on $\{(x,y)\mid x,y>0\}$. Note that every maximum of $S$ is a critical point $(a^*,b^*)$ of $S$ and satisfy $\nabla S(a^*,b^*)=0$.

Can you take it from here?

> The solution is $a^*=b^*=\sqrt[3]{V}$ so that the surface is maximized when the parallelepiped is a cube.

Comment: but i want to ask what do you mean by ∇S(a∗,b∗)?is it gradient?

Comment: @haidar yes it is: $\nabla S(x,y)=\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}S(x,y),\frac{\partial}{\partial y}S(x,y)\Big)$. The sentence "Note that every..." is related to "the theorem for extremums of a function with two variables" that you cite in the OP (although I'm not sure which theorem you are talking about exactly)

Comment: yes you are right thats what i was asking about

Answer (score 1):

The AM-GM inequality gives $S\ge 6V^{\frac23}$, with equality only when $a=b=c$.

Comment: what is the AM-GM inequality?

Comment: The arithmetic mean is greater or equal to the geometric mean, with equality if and only if all the quantities being averaged are equal. Very powerful, since it often gives an absolute maximum or minimum.

Answer (score 0):

If we eliminate z from volume and plug it into area we get half area

$ x y + V ( \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} ) $
It is possible to take Volume itself as Lagrange Multiplier for defined functions

$ F,G $ as:

$$ {x\cdot y ,  ( \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} )} = { F,G} $$ differentiate w.r.t. both variables,

$$ \frac{F_x}{F_y} = \frac{G_x}{G_y} $$ which on simplification gives $ x = y $

When y is eliminated $ z = x $ and so we get $ x = y = z = \sqrt[3]{V.}$